# How to efficiently compute a distance matrix for a large amount of data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I have a problem where I am trying to compute the nearest strings using the Edit/Levenshtein distance.

I have a list containing about 250,000 unique strings, and for each item in the list, I need to return the index of the string in the list that is closest.

My problem is that I can't just use something like pdist because it will generate a 250k^2/2 array and it'll lead to memory problems. But if I do a row by row operation like

```
def closest(s):
    """
    Returns index of minimum Levenshtein distance
    """
    distances = [levenshtein_distance(s, X[i]) for i in range(len(X))]
    minimum_distance = min(i for i in distances if i > 0)
    return distances.index(minimum_distance)
```

this will also be super inefficient as it isn't optimised like pdist and is the same as generating a dense matrix.

Would anyone have any suggestions? Many thanks!

Comment: The work you need to do is quadratic in the number of strings no matter what you try. The method you have now only requires memory linear in the sum of the length of the strings, and that's good. I expect your only real hope is to parallelize the computation. (Arrange for different processors to simultaneously run `closest()` on different `s` arguments.)

Comment: Thanks, @TimPeters - appreciate the comment!